# How to develop server side (jsp) code for open source server side (java) files?

Tags: java, jsp, webserver

I have downloaded the server side open source files; written in java from the following site:

http://corpus.quran.com/download/default.jsp

I understand that the code provided is for the language analysis and search (the part i'm interested in) functions.

I am trying in the first instance re-create the site's functionality on a local hosted web server.

As I am interested in the [morphological] search functionality (original site location is:

http://corpus.quran.com/morphologicalsearch.jsp.

Viewing the client side web page source I see that the following URL is created after the search details are provided and the search button clicked:

http://corpus.quran.com/search.jsp?q=root%3Aktb

(where "...root%3Aktb" is the search criteria)

I need your help to understand how I go about:

1) writing some server side ".jsp" code to receive the search request URL.

2) provide that as an input to the server side java code (provided by the site as open source code).

3) I have not worked out how the results generated by the java code are then sent back/displayed to the user.

Any help, including code snippets or references to online resource which detail the necessary process, would be greatly appreciated.

Let the deluge begin :)

Comment: This question is far beyond the scope of SO. You may start [here](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/partwebtier.html). Or maybe even [here](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/).

Comment: You will have to make yourself familiar with the Servlets & JSP technologies; A nice online resource to learn from is this http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html . Be aware that JSP is considered as an outdated technology

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter what would be an alternative (up to date) equivalentto JSP? I assume that the java files to which I will be sending search request information will be agnostic to how the request is managed, right?

Comment: Usual approach nowadays is to have server side REST web services with business logic (can be in servlets, but there are better frameworks for that, see e.g. [RESTEasy](https://resteasy.github.io/)), and then client side UI in something like [React](https://reactjs.org/).

Comment: @Ghulam, you could also take a look at Spring Boot, combined with Spring MVC. https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/